# Join rows in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame defined as:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"col_one": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "col_two": ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]}
).astype(str)
```

I am using this code to make all the rows become one single row with the values concatenated:

```
for c in test_df.columns:
    test_df[c] = ",".join(test_df[c].values)
print(test_df)
```

The result of this print statetement is this:

[image]

But the result I am looking for is this:

[image]

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to just do `test_df.head(1)` at the end?

Comment: @Burrito There are cases where I have hundreds of rows. It wouldn't be efficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a *self* [`cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) :

```
out = test_df.apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=",")).to_frame().T
```

Or this variant with [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) :

```
out = test_df.agg(",".join).to_frame().T
```

Output :

```
print(out)

     col_one                  col_two
0  1,2,3,4,5  one,two,three,four,five
```